# Custom Wordpress Excerpt within terms

Tags: search, terms

Is it possible to show an excerpt of the place in the feature where the search (term) result/hit is?

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't very clear - can you explain more thoroughly what the problem is and what you're looking for?

Comment: My planned is, I am using the highlight with the search resukts term keywords. The highlight is working well, but for some articles highlighted not viewable because the terms at the bottom of post contents. What I want is, the excerpt on search results near terms. So the excerpt pull based on search terms value

Comment: If you want search based on taxonomy - you can try the Search & Filter plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/

Answer (score 0):

I've used code like this, based (extremely) loosely on the plugin [relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/): (in "functions.php")

```
// Roughly based on the relevanssi_do_excerpt() (https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/, GPLv2 or later), seriously simplified.
function mytheme_search_context( $haystack, $needles, $len = 30 ) {
    $ret = '';

    $haystack = strip_tags(mytheme_strip_invisibles($haystack));
    $haystack = trim( preg_replace( array( "/\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r/", '/\s\s+/', '/&.{1,30}?;/' ), ' ', $haystack ) );

    $words = explode( ' ', $haystack );

    for ( $i = 0, $cnt = count( $words ); $i < $cnt; $i += $len ) {
        $slice = array_slice( $words, $i, $len );
        $slice = ' ' . implode( ' ', $slice );

        $search = $replace = array();
        foreach ( $needles as $needle ) {
            $pos = mb_stripos( $slice, $needle );

            if ( $pos !== false ) {
                $target = mb_substr( $slice, $pos, mb_strlen( $needle ) );
                $search[] = $target;
                $replace[] = '<strong>' . $target . '</strong>';
            }
        }
        if ( $search ) {
            if ( $i ) {
                $ret .= '&hellip; ';
            }
            if ( $i + $len > $cnt ) {
                $slice = array_slice( $words, $cnt - $len, $len );
                $slice = ' ' . implode( ' ', $slice );
                $ret .= str_replace( $search, $replace, $slice );
            } else {
                $ret .= str_replace( $search, $replace, $slice ) . ' &hellip;';
            }
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}

// Straight copy of relevanssi_strip_invisibles().
// found here: http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1106745
function mytheme_strip_invisibles( $text ) {
    $text = preg_replace(
        array(
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siu',
            '@<script[^>]*?.*?</script>@siu',
            '@<object[^>]*?.*?</object>@siu',
            '@<embed[^>]*?.*?</embed>@siu',
            '@<applet[^>]*?.*?</applet>@siu',
            '@<noscript[^>]*?.*?</noscript>@siu',
            '@<noembed[^>]*?.*?</noembed>@siu',
            '@<iframe[^>]*?.*?</iframe>@siu',
            '@<del[^>]*?.*?</del>@siu',
        ),
        ' ',
        $text );
    return $text;
}
```

Then depending on your theme (you've probably already done this), copy "search.php" to your child theme, and change the line (if it's there) `<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>` to `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>`, and then copy the theme's "content.php" to "content-search.php" in the child theme, and replace the line (or equivalent) `the_extract();` with something like

```
        if ( $mytheme_search_context = mytheme_search_context( do_shortcode( get_the_content() ), get_query_var( 'search_terms' ) ) ) {
            echo '<p>', $mytheme_search_context, '</p>';
        } elseif ( $get_the_excerpt = get_the_excerpt() ) {
            echo '<p>', strip_shortcodes( $get_the_excerpt ), '</p>';
        }
```